# How to use custom endpoint as singleType collections attribute?

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, strapi

I set up a strapi custom endpoint that returns a number `timestamp`. But I already have a config content-type with following schema.json

```
{
  "kind": "singleType",
  "collectionName": "default_conversion_currencies",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "default-conversion-currency",
    "pluralName": "default-conversion-currencies",
    "displayName": "default-conversion-currency"
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": false,
    "comment": ""
  },
  "attributes": {
    "code": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "USDT",
      "required": true
    }
  }
}
```

and i want those two attributes to be received within one request. Is there any way of addding custom api/service/controller as attribute of another content-type ?